# AngularJs $http service response Listener

Tags: angularjs, http, spring-mvc

> **REQUIREMENT:**

I need to create a statistics page where data graphs **load data at real time.**

> **CASE:**

I have a **SPRIRNG** application, with ***@EnableScheduling*** annotation, and a ***@RestController*** with ***@Scheduled(fixedRate=4000)*** annotation.

The service is properly being scheduled every 4secs and returns.

I have a **HTML page with AngularJs** where I create a **$http** request to the controller and receive the response from the controller API.

> **CONCERN:**

When I load the HTML page, it makes **$http** request to the ***@RestCOntroller*** and gets the data as result but **FOR ONE(First) TIME ONLY!**

If I need real time data then my Angular's **$http** request should be able to get result from the service each time the service returns new data, that is; each time the service is scheduled (here, 4secs).

> **QUERY:**

Is there any way or process for creating an **AngularJs listener** which actively listens the service and fetches data each time the service returns new data?

Comment: truly real-time update - `socket.io`, delay - `$timeout` / `$interval`, listeners (_within the app_) - `$rootScope.$broadcast`->`$scope.$on`

Comment: Could you show us what you have done

Comment: @AlekseySolovey: Doesn't '$rootScope.$broadcast' work for controllers only on Angular? How will this interact with Spring RestController?

Comment: you would need to establish sockets for this kind of listening